# The achitecture of a large scalable Angular app

Tags: angular, architecture

We're building a large modular Angular application currently in version 5.2.0. Since the application is modular built and each piece of the application is built by different teams in the organization everything puts together when packaging for production. There are currently many risks by having one big automated build that builds all our applications into one production ready single page application. This last step needs as for today be handled manually.

The architecture we have today looks something like this:

```
   ROOT_APP
  /   |   \
APP1 APP2 APP3
```

**ROOT_APP**

Starts the angular application and instantiates the AppComponent. All global UI elements like top navigation, systembar, dashboard and user profile settings exists in this module.

**AppX**

Developed by other parts of the organization in different repositories. When building those application we build and publish just the chunk file(s) this application outputs. Those chunks gets installed in production and gets delivered to the clients. All those application is accessed one level down in the application like `${HOST}/appx` through the Angular router.

Issues with our setup:

1. All 3pp node libraries needs to be added in ROOT_APP.
2. All `AppX` need to rely on the same version of 3pp node libraries
3. Treeshaking is not possible.
4. AOT not possible.

The setup works, but I think it's possible to do it even better and it would be interesting to hear from others, what's your experience of how to set the architecture and developing large scalable Angular apps?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know why you chose this approach, because it isn't convenient at all from what I see ...

Personnaly, in the projects I did, we had several teams that worked **on the same project**, with **version control**. We created **Angular modules** and each team worked on their module, then we created **pull requests** when we were done, PR that needed to be validated by other teams.

This means we only had **one project**, getting rid of all of your constraints at once.

Comment: Understand, in this project there are working 1200+ developers (backend included) so this approach won't work for us.

Comment: Well of course it will, that's what Git is made for ! you just need to separate your application into modules that aren't depending on each other, and this will be the exact way of working you already have, but with simplified building and dependency management. I saw this working with 200+ devs, so I'm pretty sure this can work for a thousand more :)